# HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden java ssl socket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

I am new to java and need to open a TLS connection and send data but I am getting 403 forbidden error, am I missing something in the code?

javax.net.SocketFactory basicSocketFactory = javax.net.SocketFactory.getDefault();
            java.net.Socket s = basicSocketFactory.createSocket(host,port);

```
        javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory tlsSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        s = tlsSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, true);

         if (s.isConnected()){
             System.out.println("connected"); <-passes here
         }

         java.io.PrintWriter pw = new java.io.PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());


         pw.println("POST /direct.aspx HTTP/1.1\n\r\n");
         pw.println("Host: "some host-sorry can't reveal"\n\r\n");
         pw.println("Connection: Close\n\r\n");
         pw.println("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n\r\n");
         pw.println("Content-Length: " + Integer.toString(input.length())+"\n\r\n");
         pw.println("Charset: UTF-8\n\r\n");
         pw.println(input);
         pw.flush();
         java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
         String t;
         while((t = br.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(t);
         br.close();
```

Comment: Where did you see such HTTP request? The end of line should be `\r\n` and not `\n\r\n` and there  should be another `\r\n` (empty line) at the end of the header to separate header from body. And there is no `content-length` header in your POST request. Please don't guess how HTTP works but read [the standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) or use a library which does it properly.  I really would like to have a close reason of "too lazy to read standards"  and apply it to all the posts where OP try to (badly) reimplement HTTP instead of using a library.